# What is the difference between project and subrange functions in boost::number::ublas?

Tags: boost, project, numeric, ublas

Ie, is there any difference between

```
subrange(V, 0, 3);
```

and

```
project(V, range(0,3));
```

?

I ask because I'm digging into some code that seems to use both forms (with no apparent rhyme/reason for one vs. the other), but I can't see any difference between the two... just wanted to check to make sure I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked into it, and I've confirmed there is no difference - subrange is simply an easy wrapper for a common-case of project, and in these cases:

```
subrange(V, 0, 3);
project(V, range(0,3));
```

...they end up identical. So using either should be fine, as long as you're consistent!

For the more curious... subrange does:

```
template<class V>
vector_range<V> subrange (V &data, typename V::size_type start, typename V::size_type stop) {
        typedef basic_range<typename V::size_type, typename V::difference_type> range_type;
        return vector_range<V> (data, range_type (start, stop));
    }
```

while project does:

```
template<class V>
vector_range<V> project (V &data, typename vector_range<V>::range_type const &r) {
    return vector_range<V> (data, r);
}
```

..and since vector_range::range_type is defined to be

```
typedef basic_range<size_type, difference_type> range_type;
```

...ie, exactly what is used in subrange, the two forms are identical.